# Programar C em Linux - IDE vs. editor + linha de comando

Tags: c, linux, ide, linha-de-comando, editor-de-texto

Estive a procura de uma pergunta semelhante aqui e não encontrei nada por isso se já tiver resposta peço desculpa.

Sou iniciante na Programação em C e gostava de saber se é mais indicado utilizar um IDE para a criação/edição do código, compilação e execução do código ou se é mais indicado utilizar um editor de texto do gênero Notepad++, compilar e executar o código através do terminal do Linux.

A nível de identificação de *error*'s e *warning*'s qual destes métodos fornece a informação mais completa e segura?

Ao compilarmos e executarmos o código através do terminal conseguimos ter uma melhor percepção de como funciona o código na máquina?

Comment: Lembrando ainda que você pode usar editores mais simples que chamam o compilador sem precisar entrar no terminal toda hora, como o SublimeText, o Syn (que eu uso para várias linguagens, mas é pra windows apenas) e mesmo o Notepad++. Quase todos estes editores têm uma maneira de você configurar um script para compilar seu código a um toque de tecla, mesmo sem ser uma IDE.

Comment: Sempre que tiver uma dúvida do tipo "o que é mais indicado" ou "qual é melhor" - experimente as alternativas e tire suas próprias conclusões. Você vai enriquecer seu conhecimento muito mais do que se tivesse deixado alguém decidir por você, além de descobrir o que é mais adequado para o seu caso ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A maioria do que vou dizer serve para qualquer linguagem. Farei ressalvas quando necessário.

Estou entendendo que você gostaria de ver uma comparação entre um [IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101) completo e a opção de usar um editor de código mais simples com ferramentas de linhas de comando.

Em algumas linguagens o IDE ajuda muito. Essas linguagens até foram concebidas com a ideia de auxílio de um IDE em mente. Em C isso ocorre menos. Até porque linguagens menos orientadas a objeto costumam ter um pouco menos de vantagens quando se utiliza um IDE.

Não acho que faça alguma diferença ser no Linux ou outro sistema operacional. Mas o Linux tem um cultura de usar ferramentas mais simples, de preferir a linha de comando. Isso pode influenciar na decisão.

## Experiência do programador

- Programadores novatos tendem muito a utilizar um IDE porque ele facilita a maioria das tarefas, é intuitivo e ajuda aprender aos poucos. O grande trunfo de um **IDE é ajudar a fazer as mesmas coisas de forma mais fácil**.
- Programadores mais experientes que também são mais *hardcore* se dividem entre os que gostam de IDE e os que preferem uma solução mais simplificada, mais objetiva e sem camadas intermediárias.

## Editores + linha de comando

Esses programadores gostam de ter mais controle sobre tudo o que ele está realizando. Eles desejam pouca interferência no seu trabalho. A comunhão de um editor mais simples, como o que você e outros membros já citaram ou um [VIM](https://www.vim.org/) ou [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), só para citar alguns, com as ferramentas de desenvolvimento "cruas" fazem eles serem mais produtivos, que no fim das contas é o que importa.

**Alguns** desses editores não são tão simples assim, eles **podem** ser considerados quase IDEs. Muitos são tão configuráveis e programáveis que a integração da ferramentas de desenvolvimento propriamente ditas praticamente fazem parte deles.

Não vou sair citando exemplos de editores porque isso provoca guerras santas. Cada um acha que o que ele usa é o melhor.

#### Integração

Nem sempre a integração desses editores com as ferramentas (compilador, *debugger*, *profiler*, *desassemblador*, etc.) são boas. Isto é um motivo para pensar se deve ou não escolher um editor. A integração ajuda muito, embora não seja trágico ficar sem ela.

Em alguns casos você terá que configurar muita coisa para usar bem o editor, mas por sorte, para C e outras linguagens, a maioria dos editores já possuem boas configurações.

O que pode ser mais complicado é integrar o *debugger*, provavelmente o recurso que a maioria dos programadores vão sentir mais falta de ter algo bem integrado.

Com relação ao compilador, receber *warnings* e *errors* costuma ser bem tranquilo de integrar na maioria desses editores. Então você pode ter essa informação no editor (que seja razoavelmente configurável) sem problemas, inclusive facilitando ir para o local erro apontado.

Se não tiver essa integração, não é um grande problema também. Muitos programadores acham mais produtivo usar essas ferramentas de forma independente como linha de comando no console.

## IDE

Um IDE completo pode ser vantajoso principalmente se ele já tem ferramentas específicas para a linguagem em questão.

Um IDE não fica limitado às ferramentas já citadas e **auxiliadores de código** (*sintax hightlight*, *code completation*, *help inline*, etc.), que os editores também costumam ter em maior ou menor grau.

Com um IDE você também tem **gerenciamento do projeto e arquivo de construção (*build*) da aplicação, análises estáticas extras, ferramentas de *refactoring*, buscas complexas, navegação facilitada, geradores de código, visualizadores da organização do código**, etc.

Como esses IDES costumam ser feitos ou adaptados especificamente para uma determinada linguagem eles possuem ferramentas mais adequadas que podem ir um pouco além do que um editor simples consegue.

#### Ajuda mas não faz mágica

Mas não ache que um IDE fará mágica. Principalmente em C. E lembre-se sempre que mesmo que na prática seja uma forma um pouco mais fácil de desenvolver softwares, as ferramentas mais simples podem fazer tudo o que você precisa, só será de um jeito diferente.

Raramente você terá alguma informação adicional em um IDE (isso tem mudado um pouco em alguns casos). O contrário já não é verdadeiro. Como os IDEs dependem bastante das ferramentas "cruas", nada garante que tudo o que tem na ferramenta, está disponível no IDE. Claro que um bom IDE te fornecerá tudo o que é importante, só não vai garantir as coisas mais obscuras, a última novidade do depurador no dia seguinte (os novos ciclos de desenvolvimento tem permitido isso em alguns casos).

Você **pode** perceber/entender melhor com um IDE porque é mais visual, tem mais formas de apresentar a informação, tem tudo mais a mão. Mas depende de cada pessoa, depende do estilo que a pessoa adota, do quanto conhece bem as ferramentas diversas.

#### Minimizando um dos problemas do IDE

Um IDE que usa muito o *mouse* muda demais o contexto do trabalho das mãos. Se tiver que ficar trocando do teclado para o *mouse* a todo momento, pode se tornar cansativo ou improdutivo. Mas há quem se acostume bem com isso. A recomendação geral é minimizar ou eliminar o uso do *mouse*

#### Desvantagens

Uma das principais desvantagens de um IDE é o seu **"peso"**. Em geral essas aplicações são grandes e relativamente lentas. Elas exigem máquinas bem modernas para rodar bem. Algumas são chatas para deixar do jeito que você quer e é um tipo de aplicação que tende a quebrar com uma frequência maior que o normal, até em função da intimidade que ele tem com sua aplicação.

Fazendo a ressalva que eu não levo isso tão ao pé da letra, eu questiono o programador que já não é novato que não consiga programar sem um IDE ajudando. Também não digo que o bom programador precisa se afastar de um bom IDE para provar alguma coisa.

Se IDE fosse certamente vantajoso em todos os casos, 100% dos programadores usariam um.

## Depuração

Se a sua última pergunta é sobre seguir a execução passo a passo, costuma ser mais fácil visualmente fazer isso em um IDE. Mas nada que seja impossível em alguns editores. Se quer ver as instruções sendo executadas por um *desassemblador*, é mais fácil ver em um IDE. Mas você vê tudo em um *desassemblador* de linha de comando também.

## Conclusão

Respondendo uma parte da sua pergunta original, todos os editores tem vantagens e desvantagens técnicas, mas você também deve observar o que você mais gosta, qual se sente mais confortável.

#### Como escolher

Idealmente é bom você escolher um editor ou IDE e ficar com ele para todas as linguagens que usar. Quanto melhor você souber usar uma ferramenta, melhor vai explorá-la e melhores resultados serão obtidos.

Você só vai saber ao certo o que é bom para você, testando. Você não tem nada a perder, toda experiência é válida. Pessoas aleatórias na internet não podem dizer o que é bom para você.

Você gosta de usar linha de comando? Se dá bem com isso? Costuma ter várias tarefas em console? Ou prefere um ambiente visual com tudo a um ou dois cliques de distância?

Parece que a resposta é que o gosto e *background* existente é mais importante que as vantagens de cada um. Na falta de uma métrica confiável, um estudo que indique que um lado é melhor que o outro, vou confiar no *feeling*.

#### Momento da carreira

C é uma das linguagens mais adequadas para uma solução mais simples que um IDE. Mas um novato vai sofrer bastante só na linha de comando. Por outro lado é a única forma do programador ganhar experiência com tudo o que pode ser necessário. Ninguém vai se tornar um bom desenvolvedor em C dando vários cliques em uma GUI. É o paradoxo do ovo e a galinha. Isso vale para qualquer coisa em programação. Seria melhor: aprender do jeito mais concreto, mais baixo nível e entender tudo como funciona e depois aprender as facilidades, ou é melhor ir direto para o mais abstrato, o que tem tem mais camadas escondendo a parte difícil, não te dando a base correta e completa?

#### Estilo

Se tiver que resumir a resposta eu diria que **ambos resolvem o mesmo problema com qualidade semelhantes através de estilos diferentes**.

Não ajudou muito? A intenção era essa mesmo. Não tem como dar uma resposta definitiva, só um guia para você achar a melhor solução para você. Talvez por isso ninguém quer responder.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

A resposta do Maniero está excelente na minha opinião.

A pergunta de fato é subjetiva e como está aberta posto esta resposta para a adicionar meus dois centavos a respeito do uso de IDEs vs Editor de texto para iniciar em C.

Também sou iniciante em C, para meu aprendizado cada um teve uma importância especial, resumidamente:

Os editores de texto tiveram sua contribuição inicial pois permitiram entender o básico de que, escrevendo o código em um simples texto e depois rodando um compilador, tem-se um programa executável.

Agora os IDEs tiveram um papel mais amplo, nos IDEs (em primeiro o Eclipse) foi possível ver e entender a estrutura mais ampla código, entender melhor os cabeçalhos, os *imports* as condições no preprocessador e os erros na compilação.

Tudo isto porque o Eclipse colore a sintaxe, mostra as ligações, mostra o que foi incluído ou não no código e aponta os erros.

Por fim, existe um IDE e uma série de tutoriais que teve um papel fundamental para o melhor entendimento da programação em C: [O IAR Embedded Workbench](http://www.iar.com/), ele é voltado para a programação de microcontroladores ARM e permite rodar simulações visualizando a memória e o código "descompilado" em Assembly. E isto é fantástico porque visualiza-se em tempo real, por exemplo, o que acontece na máquina quando se coloca um valor em uma variável, quando se usa um ponteiro, o que acontece quando se executa um *loop*, etc.

Pode parecer complicado mas [existe uma série de tutoriais](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPW8O6W-1chwyTzI3BHwBLbGQoPFxPAPM) que explica passo a passo todo o processo ensinando a programar em C usando o IAR para ver os resultados.

Como exemplo, com o uso desta ferramenta e do tutorial foi possível entender rapidamente, em 12min precisamente :), uma das minhas maiores dúvidas, o básico do que são e como funcionam os ponteiros.

Então, acredito que para iniciar, é necessário passar por várias ferramentas, editores, IDEs. Depois com a experiência decide-se o que mais te agrada e o que atende às suas necessidades.

Fugindo do C, sou programador Python há 5 anos, pelos menos no Python vejo que certos projetos ganham tal amplitude em complexidade (tamanho do código, número de arquivos, colaboração em time, etc) que fica muito difícil de gerenciar apenas com editores de texto, assim, minha escolha, devido a necessidade profissional, são os IDEs. (Mas não posso negar que editar código no VIM é muito divertido :) ).

Comment: Excelente complemento. Eu sou tão dinossauro que não sei como é começar com IDE :) Na primeira parte, quem não sabe, é bom notar que até o "simples" VIM permite os principais auxílios de código. Na segunda parte (sobre ARM), era algo que estava procurando para dar como exemplo de algo que IDE ajuda mais.