# É recomendável usar IDE para programar em C++?

Tags: c++, ide

Quando estava a aprender C eu programava utilizando um editor de texto e um compilador, mas como C++ é virado para POO talvez uma IDE ajude apesar deu eu não ser muito a favor de IDE's. Gostava de "ouvir" a vossa opinião porque estou realmente indeciso. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: depende cara, conheço gente que programa no notepad e é feliz, enquanto tem gente que não vive sem IDE, vai de gosto mesmo, no fim das contas, tanto faz. Eu, particularmente, uso IDE para C#, mas para Front-End eu uso notepad mesmo.

Comment: A sua pergunta implica em respostas baseadas em opiniões pessoais, portanto está fora do escopo do site.

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15794/101

Answer (score 6):

1. Ao usar uma boa IDE, você verá vários erros e *warnings* mais facilmente:

[image: Ponto 1]

2. A IDE poderá sugerir funções e parâmetros, mostrando-lhe os formatos adequados destas:

[image: Ponto 2]

3. Além disso, a IDE já preparará scripts de compilação prontos e organizará os seus arquivos de códigos-fonte e de cabeçalhos automaticamente, para que você possa começar a codificar imediatamente. Por exemplo, a compilação a seguir eu acabei de fazer sem ter que configurar uma única vírgula de script de configuração ou makefile, foi tudo gerado pela IDE:

[image: Ponto 3]

Enfim, usar ou não IDE é uma questão de gosto pessoal, e conheço muita gente que prefere não usar e muita gente que não abre mão de usar. Não é a opinião de pessoas contra ou a favor que dirá como será a sua experiência, pois isso é algo que depende muito de gosto pessoal. Entretanto, ressalto que as IDEs foram projetadas por pessoas muito inteligentes com a finalidade de otimizar a experiência de programar, tornando o programador mais produtivo, e portanto, vale a pena ao menos experimentar para decidir se você prefere usar ou não uma IDE. Além disso, caso não goste de alguma IDE em particular, pode ser que outra se adeque ao seu gosto, uma vez que há várias IDEs diferentes disponíveis para C++.